# Are network protocols and routing protocols different things?

Tags: routing, networking

When reading about network protocols it says they are a set of rules and format for communication between devices over a network, so basically an agreed way of how to communicate over a network.

But then I came across routing protocols which are described as a set of rules used by a router when communicating with its neighbours (routers). Example of routing protocols are RIP, OSPF, EIGRP.

So I'm assuming they are two different things but act similar?

Comment: Protocols are sets of rules. The protocols to which you refer are rules for communication. I'm not sure why you distinguish communications between applications on PCs and applications on routers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A *network protocol* is any protocol that is used in networking. Some popular examples are Ethernet (physical and data link layer), IPv4 (network layer), TCP (transport layer), HTTP (application layer).

A *routing protocol* is a network protocol that routers use to exchange routing information - who knows which subnet and where it is located.

In the OSI layering framework, a routing protocol provides management for the network layer and belongs to it.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. In networks there is a difference between:

- **routed protocols** like f.e. IPX, AppleTalk IP and IPv6, and
- **routing protocols** which there are  f.e. RIP/OSPF/BGP/EIGRP/IS-IS etc.

Most **routing protocols** use a **routed protocol** as transport to communicate with neighbors, but some routing protocols use a separate protocol to communicate with neighbors, instead of using a routed protocol.

I hope that clears a bit the question without explaining all the corner cases.

Comment: So I'm assuming network protocols are known as routed protocols then?

Comment: Network protocol is a very generic description, but reading your initial question in this case it is true.

Answer (score 1):

Network protocol include all protocols in entire networking concepts where as routing protocols are considered as subset of network protocols

**Network protocol includes**

1. Spaning tree protocols (STP, RSTP, MSTP)
2. Routing protocols ( rip,OSPF,bgp,EIGRP,ripv2 ,is-is,igrp)
3. Routed protocols (IPV4v4 & IPV6)
4. DHCP
   5)HSRP ,VRRP

**IPsec protocols**

1. Encapsulation security payload (ESP)
2. Authentication header(AH)

**Routing protocols**

1 ) Static routing protocols

2 ) Routing information protocols (RIP)

3 ) EIGRP

4 ) OSPF

5 ) IS-IS

6 )BGP